# Ember-Simple-Auth with Torii access user info

Tags: ember.js, google-oauth, ember-simple-auth, torii

I've been working all week to get authentication working. I have gotten it working with

- Ember-CLI
- Ember-Simple-Auth
- Torii

  - google-oauth2 provider

However I have proven unsuccessful in getting the users information from google. I have tried creating a torii-adapter as stated in their documentation but it doesn't appear to be called

```
// app/torii-adapters/application.js
export default Ember.Object.extend({
  open: function(authorization){
    console.log('authorization from adapter', authorization);
  }
});
```

I've exhausted my google-foo and am asking for your assistance. This is a great library combination for authorization however the documentation is lacking for this case, and when figured out I will be sure to contribute back.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem is. Is the above code a torii provider? What do you mean you cannot get the user information from Google?

Comment: I just want to be able to display the user account info from google (first name, last name, email, etc.) The above is a Torii Adapter but now that I think about it is not what I need. Torii says it provides this information in the session property (which is disabled by default) and Ember Simple Auth has its own which I don't see any user information in?

Comment: Ember Simple Auth defines a session and when you use the Ember Simple Auth torii authenticator then anything the torii provider resolves with will be made available via the session.

Comment: So ultimately it is down to getting the torii provider to resolve the user information (which I'm assuming isn't by default as I don't see it in session)?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to do something like {{session.currentUser}}

Comment: Read through the Ember Simple Auth README as well as the API docs to get an understanding of how the library works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I was encountering is Torii's default google-oauth2 provider doesn't access this info for you, also it uses the code workflow instead of the token workflow which is needed for the google+ API

To fix this I wrote a custom provider that uses a jquery GET request to the G+ API, I then return the userName and userEmail to access it in the session under content.

I wrote a full tutorial detailing authorizing an ember app using google start to finish [here](https://github.com/Frozenfire92/EmberAuthTutorial)

```
//app/torii-providers/google-token.js
import {configurable} from 'torii/configuration';
import Oauth2Bearer from 'torii/providers/oauth2-bearer';

var GoogleToken = Oauth2Bearer.extend({
  name: 'google-token',
  baseUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',

  // additional params that this provider requires
  requiredUrlParams: ['state'],
  optionalUrlParams: ['scope', 'request_visible_actions', 'access_type'],

  requestVisibleActions: configurable('requestVisibleActions', ''),

  accessType: configurable('accessType', ''),

  responseParams: ['token'],

  scope: configurable('scope', 'email'),

  state: configurable('state', 'STATE'),

  redirectUri: configurable('redirectUri',
                            'http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback'),

  open: function(){
      var name        = this.get('name'),
          url         = this.buildUrl(),
          redirectUri = this.get('redirectUri'),
          responseParams = this.get('responseParams');

      var client_id = this.get('client_id');

      return this.get('popup').open(url, responseParams).then(function(authData){
        var missingResponseParams = [];

        responseParams.forEach(function(param){
          if (authData[param] === undefined) {
            missingResponseParams.push(param);
          }
        });

        if (missingResponseParams.length){
          throw "The response from the provider is missing " +
                "these required response params: " + responseParams.join(', ');
        }

        return $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me", {access_token: authData.token}).then(function(user){
          return {
            userName: user.displayName,
            userEmail: user.emails[0].value,
            provider: name,
            redirectUri: redirectUri
          };
        });
      });
    }
});

export default GoogleToken;
```

Comment: can you suggest/guide me on how do implement the same thing for a facebook login via torii ? i.e Get user details from facebook based on torii's authorization token ?

Comment: Using the default torii facebook provider and then using facebook's api should work. It looks like the code in the quickstart demos this  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2